# ASP.NET MVC 5, SignalR 2.2.1 and Sessions. Using them to create a web chat

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and SignalR. I have followed some tutorials about MVC and SignalR to catch the foundations. I searched, read and tested, but nothing specific to my problem. So I will try to explain everything clearly from the first time. I am trying to create a web chat program with MVC and SignalR. Seems like I can not understood the using of SignalR and MVC and the Session handling.

I need to follow the user session and determine whether the user is logged in or not.

There will be function for creating a chat room (only for logged users).

*Option (1) Not Logged in user:*

The not logged in user must enter only a name then he will have access to some of the chat rooms. He will not be able to create new chat room.

*Option (2) Logged in user:*

The logged in user will be able to create a chat room. And join in any other chat room.

**Questions:**

1. How the creation of the new chat room should be accomplished?

   - Create the view for the new chat room dynamically in run time?
   - Create one static view and then use it only for showing the data (I mean the following: for all users and rooms I programmatically determine which user in which room is, filter all other users, all the conversation and I show the content for the specific users in specific room in that static view...)?
   - Or something else?
2. How to check if user is logged in?
3. How /and how much/ is the checking for logged in user relevant to SignalR?
4. How is the joining in a chat room accomplished?
5. Should I follow a session for not logged in user(s)?
6. Do I really need sessions for that kind of application everywhere or I only need sessions to determine if the user is logged in or not logged in?
7. Should I store messages directly to DB or I must do some kind of a buffer before inserting to DB? (Lets say I have 600 000 people chatting at the same time, will inserting directly in DB cause the database server to "overheat"?)

I think that is for now. I will edit if something comes up...

Thanks in advance to everyone who will try to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are too many questions at the same time. I would try and be more specific or you will get vague answers.

Regarding the main question, you need to learn about [SignalR authentication and authorization](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization)

Basically you can add the `[Authorize]` attribute to methods like `CreateRoom` that you want to protect. Those are only available to logged-in users. You don´t need to handle sessions or do any checking, SignalR will do it for you.

Methods not marked with `[Authorize]` are "anonymous", meaning that any user can call them.

> How is the joining in a chat room accomplished?

You could keep a static list of clients for each room and manage connections and disconnections yourself. Or better yet, you could use [SignalR groups](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups).

There is an awesome (and advanced) working chat application called [Jabbr.net](https://jabbr.net) that is made with SignalR. You can grab the [source code](https://github.com/JabbR/JabbR) and find all the answers there

Comment: Thank you for your response. The information and the links you provided were very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think probably you missed  somehow to understand the concept and features of SignalR.
So you need to re check one more time for **SignalR** as it basically used to create chat application in .NET.

Things you can search over the internet are:
* Create a chat application using SignalR. 
* Using SignalR create chat with groups.

Groups will help you to mange authorised and un authorised users Chat.

So these search will give you the best idea for all your questions and understanding.